# How to use adobe javascript to saveas a pdf file to path with dollar sign

Tags: javascript, adobe

I have two folders for demonstration and testing purposes.

One is "D:/Test"
One is "D:/$Test"

I can use this code in JavaScript debugger to save the opened pdf under "D:/Test"

```
this.saveAs({cPath:'/D/Test/a.pdf',bPromptToOverwrite: false});
```

and this work too

```
this.saveAs({cPath:'/D/Test/a$.pdf',bPromptToOverwrite: false});
```

but the following code failed to save the pdf under the path with dollar sign

```
this.saveAs({cPath:'/D/$Test/a.pdf',bPromptToOverwrite: false});
```

I googled it and not much articles talked about this issue. A article (https://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-path-dollar-sign-JavaScript-q8972.aspx) said $ cannot be used in the adobe path. But I cannot find any workaround solution, e.g. any alternative to saveAs function or any escape character available.

Thank you in advance for your help. Any ideas would be appreciated.

I structured my filing system that using $ for identification of some parameters. That is why I am trying to make the adobe to fit in my filing system.